# Why is the installationpolicy of the PSGallery does not change even when Puppet states it changed?

Tags: powershell, puppet, dsc

I am generally new to Puppet, so would need a bit of a help with the following problem:

I am trying to use this module: https://forge.puppet.com/modules/dsc/powershellget

Added this to the manifest:

```
  ## ensure PSGallery is present - relies on mod 'dsc-powershellget', '2.2.5-0-3'
  dsc_psrepository { 'Trust public gallery':
    dsc_name               => 'PSGallery',
    dsc_ensure             => 'Present',
    dsc_installationpolicy => 'Trusted',
  }
```

This got applied to the node according to the agent:

```
PS C:\Users\local_admin> puppet agent -t
Info: Using environment 'production'
...
Notice: /Stage[main]/Role::Wsus_server/Windowsfeature[UpdateServices]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Profile::Windows/Dsc_psrepository[Trust public gallery]/dsc_installationpolicy: dsc_installationpolicy changed 'Untrusted' to 'Trusted'
Notice: dsc_psrepository[{:name=>"Trust public gallery", :dsc_name=>"PSGallery"}]: Updating: Finished in 33.03 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 166.12 seconds
PS C:\Users\local_admin>
```

But when I check the actual state of the gallery, it does not seem to be updated:

```
PS C:\Users\local_admin> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2


PS C:\Users\local_admin>
```

Any notions on what am I might be missing please...?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the module you're using, not with Puppet itself.  Your best bet would be to file an issue against that, or otherwise to seek out a member of that project.